# How to speed up 8 digits combination numbers in python

Tags: python, if-statement, optimization, while-loop

I Have Code Like this

```
n = 8
Num = set()
start = 0
end = 10**n

while start < end:
  x = ''.join(['{}'.format(randint(0, 9)) for num in range(0, n)])
  if x not in Num:
    start += 1
    Num.add(x)
```

Which gave me result like this:

```
46282449
76709352
92922406
```

The point of the code above is that **I want to produce all combinations of the 8 digit numbers**, which means there are about 100 million combinations. My problem is this code takes a lot of time to process (until now this code has taken up to 7 hours more and has not stopped). Can someone give me advice on how to optimize this code?

Comment: If you have working code and you're looking for improvements, you should post your question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: You might want to use the `itertools.combinations` [more information](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/itertools-combinations-module-python-print-possible-combinations/)

Comment: If you are using `randint` then I doubt you are gonna get all possible combinations

Comment: @PCM You just need unlimited time.

Comment: Hint: when there are 99,999,999 combinations in the set already, how many times on average do you think the loop will have to try in order to find the remaining combination? How many times on average do you think it will try (and fail with) an existing combination? Now. Do you *know* what all the combinations are? Can you think of a simple way to generate all of them in order? Now, knowing that, can you think of a simple way using the `random` module to put them in a random order? (If you can't, try reading the documentation.)

Comment: Wait, do you actually want them to be in a random order? ... You do understand that `sets` *don't conceptually have an order*, right?

Comment: That said, what happened when you tried putting `python produce all combinations` into a search engine?

Comment: This isn't even a case for `itertools`. With a given `n` a simple `[f'{i:0{n}d}' for i in range(10 ** n)]` will do - at least until we run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [itertools.permutations](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/permutation-and-combination-in-python/amp/):

```
itertools.permutations(iterable, r)
```

> This method takes a list as an input and returns an object list of tuples that contain all permutations in a list form.

```
from itertools import permutations

perm_generator = permutations(range(1, 9), 8)
for p in perm_generator:
    print(p)
```

Comment: `comb_generator = combinations(range(1, 9), 8)` still produces only numbers 1 to 8 when you print it out